# Macbook Air 2017 - does not turn on, battery charging and seems to work

Tags: macbook-pro, power-management

I have a 2017 Macbook air that is giving me problems since last month. The laptop when it goes to sleep while not charging won't come back to life.

At first, the SMC reset worked but now that doesn't work either. I have tried so many things I saw online to boot it back up but it just looks like it won't come back to life after only 2 years of using it. I do not charge it all the time and when and if it does turn on, the battery holds hours of usage still. Not sure battery is a problem.

1. I have tried SMC, first it did work, but now it does not work.
2. I left it alone and sometimes it will turn on by itself after a few hours.

The problem is when I click on the start button, I hear that the fan starts for a second and turns off. Then it starts again and turns off again. In the end, I hear a little whizzing sound from the inside that can go on for hours and magically it will boot. But if it goes to sleep while not charging, same thing happens.

I have also tried unplugging the battery and running it on just the charger but then I only get the fan running really high and the laptop still would not boot.

I put it to never go to sleep once during this time but then bluetooth has problems and I feel like that can totally kill the laptop.

I don't really know about mac laptops that much and apple probably would say the logic board is the issue. I am just wondering if anyone came across something like this. I feel like some people have had similar issues but I have all the issues at once.

Update: I also think it does not completely shut down. Everytime I turn it off by holding the power button down while not charging, if i plug the charger back in, the fan just comes back on without me clicking the power button. There may be a perfect explanation to this that I do not know though

Comment: How have you unplugged the battery out of interest?

Comment: I opened the laptop basically to unplug it from the logic board. Put the plate back on, put the charger in and click on start button for like 10 seconds which starts the fan running high.

Comment: What about PRAM reset. I would not recommend messing about with the battery though, OSX expects it to be there and will exhibit (more) strange behaviour.

Comment: I have tried PRAM as well but that does not work at all to my fortune.